# How could i manually update the recyclerview of my app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android development. I intended on users to submit their information via Google Docs until I created a website for my app. I currently have a recyclerview to display posts. These posts consist of imageviews and textviews. My question is what is the most efficient way I could update my recylerview to display their submitted information if approved. If not plausible what would you suggest to manage the content in my program? Also keep in my mind I plan on developing the same application in Ios in the future and would like for each app to display the same information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could represent the data fetched from your web service in an SQLite Database (a good tutorial on how to create/access sqlite databases in android can be found here: 
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/).

Then you could use a `CursorLoader` and a `CursorAdapter` for the RecyclerView and swap the cursor when the loader finishes.

If you are modifying your dataset simply call `onContentChanged()` and your loader will requery and publish the results automatically.

Here you'll find a decent `CursorAdapter` implementation for RecyclerView: https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59

And here is a good documentation on how to use the `CursorLoader` with the `LoaderCallbacks`: https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html